# Disabling inline constraints in Visual studio table designer

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

It would be grand if there were a way to disable scripting inline constraints in the VS table designer. Is there a way?

The reason I'm after this behavior is that [Insight.Database.Schema](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database.Schema) doesn't support inline constraints.

[image: default behavior]

So instead, I'd like it to add this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Security_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
([ID])
GO
```

Comment: You *might* be able to move other constraints out of line by fiddling around with the DBMS type/compatibility settings, but PRIMARY KEY in-line, is ISO (and practical) standard, and highly recommended anyway as Tables should always have Primary Keys.  You should take this back to the Insight folks and ask them to support the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name
```

You can simply add a constraint 1st and then disable it using above statement.